# .mdf file does not show in VS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mdf

I am using `VS 2013 express for web`. By using Code First Paradigm I stored data in `LocalDB`. Now file `Movie.mdf` has been created and shows data but this does not appear in `App_Data` folder. I refreshed it and restarted VS but still .mdf files does not appear in that folder.

Comment: Are you also displaying hidden files in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the files generated outside of VS, you need to either include it in the project or `Show all files` in Solution explorer.